# Getting null value for friends while retrieving data from Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get friends list from Facebook using  Facebook C# SDK.

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic me = fb.Get("me");
```

But I am getting all other data from **me** except friends related(id,name..) data,

its always giving null value.

Does anyone know what is the Problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "problem" is stated in the docs:

> Friend list now only returns friends **who also use your app**: The list of friends returned via the `/me/friends` endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_login

Answer (score 0):

FB has (somewhat) recently changed their API such that when you request the logged in user's friends, you only get those friends who are also using your FB application.

Unless you register your FB app as a game, you will not be able to see all of the logged in user's friends, only those who have also logged into your app, and have not disabled the option to show up in other people's friend lists.

Be aware that you can't simply lie that you are making a game, FB has to review your app before giving you persmissions to see the full friends list.